# How to add Signup link in description of Custom Teams app Manifest Json

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

i need to add an login link in description  to a MS Teams App as part of the information display before the app is installed. Documentation does mention a how to add link but how can I put it on the app's manifest/info like the image below?

[So as per in screenshot i want to add link in description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cyzv.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue , what are you trying to achieve? Any screenshot/detailed explanation will be helpful

Comment: check screenshot

Answer (score 2):

In the manifest in description section if you want to add hyperlink, you can do as below format:

```
    "description": {
    "short": "Sample Decription",
    "full": "FullDecsLink [FullLink](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/)"
  },
```

Attaching screenshot for reference:
[image]

Comment: That markdown no longer works to show a hyperlink in the full description from the Teams Admin center.

Comment: You are right, in Teams admin center the markdown doesn't work. We are checking with engineering team regarding the difference in behaviour. We will inform you once we get any update from them. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!